# Is Saturated Fat really as bad for you as people believe?

Tags: cholesterol, fat

So many people say Saturated Fats is bad for you and you shouldn't eat too much fatty meats or dairy because they lead to high cholesterol. Everyone just takes this as fact without asking for proof.

Does anyone know of any studies that show proof of this?

If someone eats a number of calories that are equal to or less than their daily caloric needs, does the amount of Saturated Fat in their diet really make a difference?

Additionally, body fat is saturated fat. So, if I'm burning my own fat, isn't that just like eating the same amount of calories worth of saturated fat as I have burned? What's the difference.

Please post links to sources with your answers. Thanks.

Comment: related link: 7 Reasons to Eat More Saturated Fat by Tim Ferriss - http://www.fourhourworkweek.com/blog/2009/06/06/saturated-fat/

Comment: What makes you think body fat is saturated?

Comment: Is it not? I guess that relates to how body fat and saturated fat from diet differ. Any sources to show info about this?

Comment: duplicate? http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1184/does-the-existence-of-trans-fat-invalidate-years-of-research-on-saturated-fats/1187#1187

Comment: also potential duplicate: http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1219/what-are-the-nutritional-benefits-of-saturated-fats

Comment: @Doug and others interested. You may want to go a little easy on the "duplicate" excitement. Fitness/Nutrition is a BETA and it's, well, it's not doing real well at the moment. I've heard people say on other betas you have to let them run a little, there's a danger in over-moderating (no matter how much fun moderating is). Good luck, hope it makes it out of beta!

Comment: Keep in mind that there are [over 30](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_saturated_fatty_acids) kinds of saturated fatty acids, and they all have unique effects in different situations.

Answer (score 6):

Saturated fats are good for you - 50 percent or more of our cell membrane phospholipids are saturated. The anti-saturated fat campaign was launched by U.S. vegetable interests wanting us to eat margarine, Crisco, and trans fat.

Thanks to them, obesity and diabetes have become the Twin Tower epidemics of our time! [This is an excellent link](http://www.sott.net/articles/show/232539-Enjoy-Saturated-Fats-They-re-Good-for-You-); the truth about saturated fat.

Answer (score 5):

Definitely conventional wisdom needs to be questioned in a methodical way.

Gary Taubes has written a lot about Saturated Fat, and while I can understand it while I read, I find it difficult to explain from scratch.

However, here's a good [New York Times Article](http://tierneylab.blogs.nytimes.com/2008/07/21/good-news-on-saturated-fat/) on Saturated Fats which shows that they aren't the enemy that the experts make them out to be.